# Using Event Grid, is it possible to trigger a logic app when a resource is created/deleted in Azure?

Tags: azure, events, notifications, resources

I would like to know if using Event Grid, is it possible to have a logic app triggered when any resource is deployed on a Azure Subscription.

The use case is :

- Somebody creates/deletes a resource on a particular Azure subscription
- It sends a event in Event Grid (not sure about that ?)
- A logic app is then triggered when such event occurs, this logic app will send notification in a Teams channel.

The goal here is to have a simple and basic helicopter view on what's happening on this sub.

For testing purposes, I've created a logic app and add a "**When a resource event occurs**" trigger with **Microsoft.Resources.ResourceGroups** and these event types :

```
Microsoft.Resources.ResourceActionSuccess  
Microsoft.Resources.ResourceDeleteSuccess  
Microsoft.Resources.ResourceWriteSuccess
```

[image]

Not sure I'm exploring here.

Then I've deployed a **storageaccount**, but I get notifications even when "Reviewing" the deployment just before the resource is actually deployed.

Once deployed, I also have random notifications (even if the storage account is not used, some kind of background activities I guess ?)

Answer (score 0):

As per this [Official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-schema-resource-groups?tabs=event-grid-event-schema#available-event-types):

> Resource events are created for PUT, PATCH, POST, and DELETE operations that are sent to `management.azure.com`. GET operations don't create events.

Hence you are receiving multiple triggers. For minimal triggers you can add the filters for the deployment. Below is the flow I'm using.

[image]

Below is the complete JSON of my logic app

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Send_an_email_(V2)": {
                "inputs": {
                    "body": {
                        "Body": "<p>@{triggerBody()?['subject']} has been created</p>",
                        "Importance": "Normal",
                        "Subject": "xxx",
                        "To": "xxx"
                    },
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['office365']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "post",
                    "path": "/v2/Mail"
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {
            "$connections": {
                "defaultValue": {},
                "type": "Object"
            }
        },
        "triggers": {
            "When_a_resource_event_occurs": {
                "conditions": [],
                "inputs": {
                    "body": {
                        "properties": {
                            "destination": {
                                "endpointType": "webhook",
                                "properties": {
                                    "endpointUrl": "@{listCallbackUrl()}"
                                }
                            },
                            "filter": {
                                "includedEventTypes": [
                                    "Microsoft.Resources.ResourceDeleteSuccess",
                                    "Microsoft.Resources.ResourceActionSuccess"
                                ],
                                "subjectBeginsWith": "/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Resources/deployments"
                            },
                            "topic": "/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/xxx"
                        }
                    },
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azureeventgrid']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "path": "/subscriptions/@{encodeURIComponent('xxx')}/providers/@{encodeURIComponent('Microsoft.Resources.ResourceGroups')}/resource/eventSubscriptions",
                    "queries": {
                        "x-ms-api-version": "2017-09-15-preview"
                    }
                },
                "splitOn": "@triggerBody()",
                "type": "ApiConnectionWebhook"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {
        "$connections": {
            "value": {
                "azureeventgrid": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/azureeventgrid",
                    "connectionName": "azureeventgrid",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/eastus/managedApis/azureeventgrid"
                },
                "office365": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/office365",
                    "connectionName": "office365",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/eastus/managedApis/office365"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I was able to have clean notifications on resource deletion. Unfortunately, I didn't see particular events for resource creation. I saw notifications from policies applying to newly created resources, but that produces too much noise.

So I gave up and now use a scheduled KQL request on the AzureActivity table, everything is fine now.

Thanks again for your help !

Comment: I have tried filtering the results using `/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Resources/deployments` which gave me better results for creation.